# Extracting data from a nested variant/JSON column in snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the data I have from a Json file which is loaded into snowflake variant table

{
"ID": "abc1234",
"auditTypes": [],
"categoryID": "5679cdef",
"customerID": "5679cdef",
"description": "test.",
"enteredByID": null,
"entryDate": "2020-01-06T15:07:59:367-0500",
"etl_load_ts": "2021-04-22_14:41:35:828",
"extRefID": null,
"hasDocuments": false,
"hasMessages": false,
"hasNotes": false,
"isActive": true,
"lastUpdateDate": "2021-04-15T11:32:21:311-0400",
"lastUpdatedByID": "12345678abcd",
"name": "Program: test,
"objCode": "test",
"ownerID": "1234test",
"parameterValues": {
"DE:Program ": "Yes",
"DE:WSP PRG Executive Status Summary": "test summary.",
"DE:WSP PRG Financial Partner": "{"objCode":"USER","name":"first last","ID":"abcd1234"}",
"DE:WSP PRG GPM Partner": "{"objCode":"USER","name":"First Last","ID":"abcdefgh1233"}",
"DE:WSP PRG KD-1 Reason": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG KD-2 Reason": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision Date Approved 1": "2021-02-01",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision Date Approved 2": "2021-02-01",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision Description 1": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision Description 2": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision ID 1": "0000",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision ID 2": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision Owner 1": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Decision Owner 2": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Dependencies 1": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Dependencies 2": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Description 1": "test project.",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Description 2": "---",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Impact 1": "2",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Impact 2": "-",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Impact to Cost 1": "Indirect",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Impact to Cost 2": "---",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Impact to Sched 1": "Yes",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Impact to Sched 2": "---",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Probability 1": "-",
"DE:WSP PRG Key R/I Probability 2": "-",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Risk/Issue 1": "Issue",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Risk/Issue 2": "---",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Risk/Issue Choice 1": "efff",
"DE:WSP PRG Key Risk/Issue Choice 2": "none",
"DE:WSP PRG Overall Health": "Yellow",
"DE:WSP PRG Primary Business Value": "test description.",
"DE:WSP PRG Program Code #": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Program Sponsor": "{"objCode":"USER","name":"First last","ID":"abcdef123"}",
"DE:WSP PRG Program Turned Red": "2021-02-01",
"DE:WSP PRG Target For Green": "2021-03-03",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming MS-1 Date": "2021-03-15",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming MS-2 Date": "2021-02-26",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming MS-3 Date": "2021-03-15",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming MS-4 Date": "2021-03-22",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming Milestone 1": "test",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming Milestone 2": "123-test",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming Milestone 3": "N/A",
"DE:WSP PRG Upcoming Milestone 4": "N/A"
},
"portfolioID": "abcdefgh123",
"securityRootID": "efgh123",
"securityRootObjCode": "test"
}
and I want to extract 'First Last' from the value `{\"objCode\":\"USER\",\"name\":\"First Last\",\"ID\":\"abcd1233\"}`, for the column `DE: test Partner` from the below example.

Comment: preserve the question and title even if you got the answer

Comment: If you want the data to be truly removed (we can see it all in the question history), you'll need to click Flag and use "In need of moderator attention" and ask them to remove the data from the history. But really, you should just delete the question altogether if that's all you are going to leave behind.

Comment: I am not able to delete the question as It says *You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it*. I did flag it for moderator's attention to delete the data from both question and comment section.

Answer (score 1):

`parse_json(parse_json(val):"parameterValues"."AR:WSP PRG GPM"):name` returns the desired value.

(Edit: SQL example deleted by OP request)